# Stripes Framework, Filebean and File object

Tags: file-upload, stripes

What would be the best way to access the File object that is contained in the FileBean in Stripes? I am trying to store the file in Amazon's S3 and it requires a byte array. Seems simple enough if I can get to the File object.

Answer (score 1):

`FileBean` has a [`getInputStream()`](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/FileBean.html#getInputStream%28%29) method which allows to read every byte from the FileBean. If you really want to store everything in memory in a byte array (which is a bad idea, especially if files can be large), then read evrything from the stream and write it to a ByteArrayOutputStream:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
InputStream in = fileBean.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int read;
while ((read = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
byte[] contentAsByteArray = out.toByteArray();
```